# how to figure out what directory corresponds to my PCI device in linux

Tags: linux, pci

The question is pretty much in the title:

How to figure out what directory corresponds to my PCI device in `linux`?

For example:
My VGA controller
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])` corresponds to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0`. I figured it out by experimentation.  What I want to know if there exists some sort of a table that says that a given device corresponds to a given directory in `linux`